# T-invariance #homework

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V$ be a vector space and let $T \in L(V)$. Given a $T$-invariant subspace $U$ is it true that exists a $T$-invariant space $W$ such that $V = U \oplus W $?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Let $V=\mathbb{R}^2$, $T\in L(\mathbb{R}^2)$ be given by $T(x,y)=(0,x)$ and $U=\left\{0\right\}\times\mathbb{R}$. Obviously, $T(U)=\left\{0\right\}\subseteq U$, so $U$ is $T$-invariant. If $W$ is a subspace of $V$ such that $V=U\oplus W$, then there exists some $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $W=\mathbb{R}(1,\alpha)=\left\{(x,\alpha x):x\in\mathbb{R}\right\}$.

If $W$ were $T$-invariant, then $(0,1)=T(1,\alpha)\in W$, so $1=\alpha 0=0$, an absurd.